# Rewrite SQL query to remove GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble with my Database doing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM main_cue 
WHERE group_id IN %s
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(group_id, %s) LIMIT 25, 
 (ordered_group_ids, ordered_group_ids_as_csv)
```

I think it has to do with the `GROUP BY group_id` clause. Is there another more 'valid' way to do the above query?

Comment: Which the aim of your query?

Comment: What exactly is "some trouble" ?

Comment: Write your table structure.

Comment: is it throwing any error , if yes then post it here

Comment: `SELECT *` doesn't work with `GROUP BY`...

Comment: @axiac: it does (somewhat) with MySQL (to the extent that MySQL won't reject it)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure, MySQL does not reject it, it runs and returns some data, the programmer is puzzled why it doesn't return what they expect a.s.o. I should probably say "It does not work as you might think." :-)

Comment: @axiac: that's why I wrote "somewhat" ;)

Comment: What is %s? Why is there a quote after 25? This doesn't look like SQL only. Are you mixing two languages here? PHP with SQL maybe? Show your original statement with proper single and/or double quotes etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `GROUP BY`, then the `SELECT` clause can only contain:

- columns that also appear the `GROUP BY` clause
- aggregates, e.g. `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(SomeColumnNotInTheGroupByClause)`

It is not allowed to have a column in the select list that that does *not* appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

To understand why this is, consider the following table:

```
Foo   FooDesc   Bar   BarDesc
---   -------   ---   -------
 1    SomeOne   101   John
 1    SomeOne   102   Paul
 2    SomeTwo   201   George
 2    SomeTwo   202   Arnold
```

This is invalid:

```
SELECT Foo, FooDesc, Bar, BarDesc
FROM Table
GROUP BY Foo
```

and so is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
GROUP BY Foo
```

because the database engine cannot decide which `Bar` (and `BarDesc`) to adopt in the result set:

```
Foo   FooDesc   Bar
---   -------   ---
 1    SomeOne   101 or 102 ???
 2    SomeTwo   201 or 202 ???
```

Even this is illegal, because nobody guarantees `FooDesc` uniquely follows `Foo`:

```
SELECT Foo, FooDesc
FROM Table
GROUP BY Foo
```

You'll have to make it explicit that `FooDesc` is equally duplicate as `Foo`:

```
SELECT Foo, FooDesc
FROM Table
GROUP BY Foo, FooDesc
```

If you want to have any of the other columns (pick one randomly?), than you might consider abusing an aggregate.

```
SELECT Foo, FooDesc, MIN(Bar), MIN(BarDesc)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Foo, FooDesc
```

But do keep in mind that `MIN(Bar)` and `MIN(BarDesc)` may pick values from different rows.

```
Foo   FooDesc   Bar   BarDesc
---   -------   ---   -------
 1    SomeOne   101   John
 2    SomeTwo   201   Arnold
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the query above valid? AFAIK, 'SELECT *' cannot be used with GROUP BY. If you want all rows anyway, what's the use of 'GROUP BY' at all?

Comment: Actually MySQL does allow to use `GROUP BY`  like that - but it will simply return random ("indeterminate") results rather than throwing an error.

Comment: Even if it can be done, it's a bad idea. Follow the general GROUP BY rule - If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. - and you'll safe!